# Keeping money formatting in formula Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to transfer some information from one cell to another using below formula:

`="£"&D14&" will be refunded"`

The information in cell D14 is presented as £69,500 however when I use the above formula it comes out with:

`£69500 will be refunded`

It has no commas in it. Is there anyway to make it so the commas carry across?

Comment: Are you doing this in excel or google sheets? You tag both so I am not sure given the title says google sheets.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put more formula `TEXT(number,format)`

```
="£"&TEXT(D14,"#,##0.00")&" will be refunded"
```

For Google Sheets, I hope Excel will work too